# Abel-Ruffini Theorem Intuition

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I want to be able to understand the Abel-Ruffini theorem, however to me it is quite complicated. I don't understand the correspondence between the Galois group associated with a quintic being unsolvable and the inability of the quintic to be expressed in a finite series of roots. If someone could give any intuition to the theorem or any helpful links I'd appreciate it.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2515874/72031